# Can I render a different SVG image based on the user's language using i18next in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, internationalization, i18next

I have an svg image imported as a React component like this:

```
import {ReactComponent as img} from '../img/img_en.svg';
```

But I also have a french version of this image that I would like to render when the user selects french as language.

```
import {ReactComponent as img} from '../img/img_fr.svg';
```

Any idea how I should do this? Tried looking into it without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic `import` based on the current language e.g

```
const module = await import(`../img/img_${i18next.language}.svg;`);
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import
https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#language